# Display fullscreen mode on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make a frame in Tkinter display in fullscreen mode? I saw this code, and it's very useful…:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> root.overrideredirect(True)
>>> root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
```

…but is it possible to edit the code so that hitting  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  automatically makes the window "Restore down"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This creates a fullscreen window. Pressing `Escape` resizes the window to '200x200+0+0' by default. If you move or resize the window, `Escape` toggles between the current geometry and the previous geometry.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

root=tk.Tk()
app=FullScreenApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: note: with `root.overrideredirect(True)` the `<Escape>` doesn't call anything on my machine (Ubuntu). Without `root.overrideredirect` the title bar is shown.

Comment: This does not work for me. The only thing it does is maximise the window.

Comment: This is not fullscreen but maximised... not quite the same, for true fullscreen, see answer from @Shule

Comment: `+0+0` part in `self._geom` and method `geometry' is not obligatory. You should put it only if explicitly placing window somewhere on the screen

Answer (score 111):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Tk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)  # substitute `Tk` for whatever your `Tk()` object is called
```

You can use `wm_attributes` instead of `attributes`, too.

Then just bind the escape key and add this to the handler:

```
Tk.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
```

An answer to another question alluded to this (with `wm_attributes`). So, that's how I found out. But, no one just directly went out and said it was the answer for some reason. So, I figured it was worth posting.

Here's a working example (tested on Xubuntu 14.04) that uses F11 to toggle fullscreen on and off and where escape will turn it off only:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Just checking your Python version to import Tkinter properly.
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *


class Fullscreen_Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.attributes('-zoomed', True)  # This just maximizes it so we can see the window. It's nothing to do with fullscreen.
        self.frame = Frame(self.tk)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.state = False
        self.tk.bind("<F11>", self.toggle_fullscreen)
        self.tk.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)

    def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state  # Just toggling the boolean
        self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)
        return "break"

    def end_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = False
        self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
        return "break"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Fullscreen_Window()
    w.tk.mainloop()
```

If you want to hide a menu, too, there are only two ways I've found to do that. One is to destroy it. The other is to make a blank menu to switch between.

```
self.tk.config(menu=self.blank_menu)  # self.blank_menu is a Menu object
```

Then switch it back to your menu when you want it to show up again.

```
self.tk.config(menu=self.menu)  # self.menu is your menu.
```

Comment: Why are you manually using `w.tk.destroy`? I have never seen this in a Python Tk app before.

Comment: @exhuma (I didn't see your comment until now for some reason.) Good question. Thanks for pointing that out. It seems unnecessary here. I think I saw someone else do it when I was first starting Tkinter programming, and I kept it up without thinking about it much. However, there may have been a reason for it in some program or other that I was programming once, but I don't know what that reason was. Whatever the case, it doesn't hurt the execution, but I'll edit it out of the code here and put the mainloop outside of the constructor, too.

Comment: @exhuma I found some reason behind it. Apparently, some development environments malfunction without it (although you don't seem to need it in the regular Python environment). This link provides a code example and an explanation: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm

Comment: Does this basically give you the ability to run a kiosk using TKinter?

Comment: @BillGreer Basically, yeah, but with the example above you could still press Alt+F4 to close the program and stuff, and it's programmed so pressing F11 again, or Esc will exit that mode. You could change the program, though, of course, and maybe get a secure kiosk mode, but I haven't tried that. You'd have to override a bunch of key bindings, at the very least.

Answer (score 31):

I think if you are looking for fullscreen only, no need to set geometry or maxsize etc.

You just need to do this:

-If you are working on ubuntu:

```
root=tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

-and if you are working on windows:

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

Now for toggling between fullscreen, for minimising it to taskbar you can use:

```
Root.iconify()
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's a simple solution with lambdas:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.bind("<F11>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen",
                                    not root.attributes("-fullscreen")))
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", False))
root.mainloop()
```

This will make the screen exit fullscreen when escape is pressed, and toggle fullscreen when F11 is pressed.

Answer (score 12):

This will create a completely fullscreen window on mac (with no visible menubar) without messing up keybindings

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah mate i was trying to do the same in windows, and what helped me was a bit of lambdas with the `root.state()` method.

```
root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: root.state('normal'))
root.bind('<F11>', lambda event: root.state('zoomed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
# importing tkinter for gui
import tkinter as tk


# creating window
window = tk.Tk()
 
# setting attribute
window.state('zoomed')
window.title("Full window")
 
# creating text label to display on window screen
label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello world!")
label.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

If you want to hide everything except the window, you can also use:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.title("FullScreen")
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello! Press  logo on the keypad > select the python logo > Close window to close")
labela = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.pack()
labela.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -6):

```
root = Tk()
root.geomentry('1599x1499')
```

Comment: This answer assumes the dimensions of the screen.  This isn't useful if someone has a different sized screen, or the code is expected to run on machines with different screen sizes.  A good answer would show how to obtain the screen dimensions (but without duplicating any of the existing answers).