# Tkinter full screen

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen

I used [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7966437/263078) to attempt full screen in Windows, and this is what it gave me:

[image: Full Screen]

How can I fix this?  It seems like full screen isn't supported at all or something with `Tkinter`.  It's Windows 8, if that matters.  It's also Python v2.7.2.

Comment: That  looks full screen to me. What were  you expecting different?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to fix. The Tk windows border seems a little off; however that can be fixed easily.

Comment: The goal was to be full screen, as in the display mode a game would go into when you selected full screen mode.  Window decoration along with task bar hopefully shouldn't be shown.

Comment: @TND: ok. Most people (in Tkinter circles, anyway) consider "full screen" to include the borders. Your question would be more clear if you explicitly mention you don't want the window decorations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `win.state('zoomed')`, where `win` is your Tk window instance.

Edit :

Try something like this. Simply treat this class like a Tk window class.

```
class Void (tk.Tk) :
    def __init__ (self, color='black') :
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.wm_state('zoomed')
        self.config(bg=color)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
```

Comment: Closer to, but not quite the goal.