# Make a tkinter window fullscreen

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a program that goes full screen and when I mean full screen I don't mean like maximized I mean like it covers the whole screen so like you can't see the taskbar and all that,

Any Ideas?, Thanks In Advance!

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-toplevel-fullscreen.htm) to a tutorial for making a fullscreen window (window the size of the screen, with title bar and start menu suppressed) with Tkinter. It looks like originally the poster wanted to make a slideshow application, and just posted their code for fullscreen.