# Python full-screen graphics

Tags: python

I would like to create a Python program on Linux supporting simple graphics such as those provided by John Zelle's [graphics.py package](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html). However, I need the graphics to be displayed full-screen, i.e., without the window title bar etc. The graphics.py package doesn't seem to support this. What is the easiest way to plot simple graphics on a full screen in Python?

Comment: Primaly opinion-based. And what about tkinter, pygame, qt, etc.? Just use Google to find much graphic packages.

Comment: FWIW, the window manager should let you display any window in full-screen mode. Eg, in KDE  in the window's title bar's Advanced menu there's a Fullscreen option. You can activate that option with the Alt F3-v-f key sequence; you need to use that key sequence to return from Fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to make python GUI and graphics is with the tkinter package, [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) tutorial should get you started. As for full screen graphics,
add the fullscreen attribute to your tk object:

```
Tk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter) question for alternate answers.

If you want to stick with graphics.py, I would give the window the same height and width as your resolution, on windows:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

win = GraphWin('Face', width, height)
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3129330/3838430), not so sure on the linux way.

Also check out [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) for another way to make a GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Was hoping for a solution that would use graphics.py, but playing around with the underlying Tkinter indeed seems more complicated than just using Tkinter's canvas directly.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help :)