# How to show minimize and maximize buttons tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code below is a section of a project I am working on in tkinter. When I call the `-fullscreen=True, the close out button in the top right disappears. Is there any way to fix this?

```
def homeScreen():

    global home

    home = Tk()
    home.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    listButton = Button(home, text = 'Listify', command = listifyScreen)
    enterButton = Button(home, text = 'No Enter', command = enterScreen)
    #separateButton = Button(home, text = 'Separate', command = separateScreen)

    listButton.pack()
    enterButton.pack()

    home.mainloop()

homeScreen()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display fullscreen mode on Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter)

Comment: Do not set the `-fullscreen` attribute if you don't want it fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting your tkinter home screen to fullscreen (which does what it is meant to do and removes the min/max and close buttons) just set your tkinter home screen size to match your screen resolution.

You can do this by using `home.minsize(width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)` right after `home = Tk()`.

I hope this helps!

Note: if you are using windows, do check the display settings for scale and layout options. If they're set to something different than 100%, do rescale your `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make you Application Window to be full-screen at starting you can follow this process:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Window Title")
        self.master.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        # --- This is the code you need --- #
        screen_width = str(self.master.winfo_screenwidth())
        screen_height = str(self.master.winfo_screenheight())
        self.master.geometry(screen_width + "x" + screen_height + "+0+0")

        self.listButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='Listify')
        self.listButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.enterButton = tk.Button(self.master, text='No Enter')
        self.enterButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        # ---  --- #

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```