# Make Tkinter window window full screen, and make it show taskbar, even though it has no titlebar

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen

I am trying to make a Tkinter app, and it has no title bar.

I have added **revisability with size grip, moving the window around and minimizing**

However, I am trying to make the Tkinter window *full sized*, AND SHOW THE TASKBAR

here is my code

```py
def funel():
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.state('zoomed')
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    messagebox.showerror("This feature is not added yet", "This feature is not added yet. Please give me help")
    fullscreen_btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: funel_exit())
```

So yeah... it Fullscreen's, however it does hide the taskbar. I WANT THE TASKBAR NOT TO BE HIDDEN

if my question aint clear, please inform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display fullscreen mode on Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter)

Comment: There is only one issue. It does not account for the taskbar. When I use it, it Fullscreen's the window, but hides the taskbar also. I am trying to make Fullscreen window while showing taskbar with no tkinter titlebar,